# Redirect to alternate url using the variable declared after first slash

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, virtualhost, httpd.conf, slash

Ok, Ive checked this site and still I am confused about how to do this...

I need to take a url like this

subdomain.domain.com/1234

and redirect to a url like this

http://assets.subdomain.domain/php/store.php?store_num=1234

utilizing the numbers after the slash as a get variable

Here is what I have in my .conf file so far.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName assets.subdomain.domain.com
  ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com/*
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/prod/subdomain.domain.com/assets/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://assets.subdomain.domain/php/store.php?store_num=$1 [L,QSA]         
</VirtualHost>
```

As a side note, my .conf file is pretty big and has a lot of other vhosts in it, so I'm not sure if this isn't working because there is something else in the .conf file that is overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable mod_rewrite by adding a [RewriteEngine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) directive.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://assets.subdomain.domain/php/store.php?store_num=$1 [L,QSA]
```